# How to update an object in a List<> in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, generics

I have a `List<>` of custom objects.

I need to find an object in this list by some property which is unique and update another property of this object.

What is the quickest way to do it?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Using Linq to find the object you can do:

```
var obj = myList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MyProperty == myValue);
if (obj != null) obj.OtherProperty = newValue;
```

But in this case you might want to save the List into a Dictionary and use this instead:

```
// ... define after getting the List/Enumerable/whatever
var dict = myList.ToDictionary(x => x.MyProperty);
// ... somewhere in code
MyObject found;
if (dict.TryGetValue(myValue, out found)) found.OtherProperty = newValue;
```

Comment: Thanks CKoenig, will this get a reference to `obj` or value(copy)? in other words, will be the object inside the list changed?

Comment: I think that this would not work if the object is of type struct, make it a class:)

Comment: Because you have a list of custom objects (assuming its a class and not a struct), you're dealing with a reference type, it will be a reference to that object and modifying it will "persist" - it will modify the object in the collection.

Comment: this will find the reference (so yes it will be the object in the list) and it should work with structs too - but to be honest I had to try to be sure there - but I don't see why not ATM

Comment: @CKoenig - It wouldn't work with structs, added a response below with code example to demonstrate

Comment: Is this faster than doing something like `foreach(Object o in myList){ if (o.MyProperty == myValue){o.MyProperty = newValue}}` ?

Comment: @MrDysprosium yours will loop the hole collection even if it's already the first element (so no this will not be faster) - if you add a break condition it might be faster but I doubt it *will matter/be noticeable* (depends on how the compiler handles the FirstOrDefault) - of course if your `Object` is .net's `Object` base class it will not compile at all - but that's probably just because the question asked about custom objects

Comment: If `mylist` is truly a `List<T>`, use the `Find` or `FindIndex` method to do the lookup. `FirstOrDefault` is a LINQ method and may add a little overhead you may not want. If the list is already sorted, the `BinarySearch` method (and a custom comparer on the element class) to look up the index is even faster for bigger lists.

Comment: Why would the second proferred method be preferable to the first?

Answer (score 45):

Just to add to CKoenig's response. His answer will work as long as the class you're dealing with is a reference type (like a class). If the custom object were a struct, this is a value type, and the results of `.FirstOrDefault` will give you a local copy of that, which will mean it won't persist back to the collection, as this example shows:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public int TheValue { get; set; }
}
```

Test code:

```
List<MyStruct> coll = new List<MyStruct> {
                                            new MyStruct {TheValue = 10},
                                            new MyStruct {TheValue = 1},
                                            new MyStruct {TheValue = 145},
                                            };
var found = coll.FirstOrDefault(c => c.TheValue == 1);
found.TheValue = 12;

foreach (var myStruct in coll)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myStruct.TheValue);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

The output is 10,1,145

Change the struct to a class and the output is 10,12,145

HTH

Comment: ok - thanks. my guess woult have been that you get a reference to the struct as well instead of a local copy.

Comment: 11 years later. This was the answer for me.  Very non-intuitive for me though.

Answer (score 26):

or without linq

```
foreach(MyObject obj in myList)
{
   if(obj.prop == someValue)
   {
     obj.otherProp = newValue;
     break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is obvious answer, but I don't want to use foreach, I guess this is the slowest way to do it

Comment: Can anyone comment on whether the LINQ method above is actually more efficient than this one?

Comment: If there is any difference, the linq version is probably slower.

Comment: @Burjua The perception is that we can see the actual loop happening in the foreach block, whereas in Linq/Lambda we don't, so we assume foreach is slower and try to avoid it. Reality is foreach/for/while loops are much faster.

Comment: Well slower/ faster I don't know which... but in my case I was dealing with small records anyway and didn't want to think about it to much. This worked! Nice touch with the break;

Answer (score 15):

Can also try.

```
 _lstProductDetail.Where(S => S.ProductID == "")
        .Select(S => { S.ProductPcs = "Update Value" ; return S; }).ToList();
```

Comment: This works with a list or an array, but not a IEnumerable

Answer (score 8):

You can do somthing like :

```
if (product != null) {
    var products = Repository.Products;
    var indexOf = products.IndexOf(products.Find(p => p.Id == product.Id));
    Repository.Products[indexOf] = product;
    // or 
    Repository.Products[indexOf].prop = product.prop;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var itemIndex = listObject.FindIndex(x => x == SomeSpecialCondition());
var item = listObject.ElementAt(itemIndex);
item.SomePropYouWantToChange = "yourNewValue";
```

Comment: There's no need to remove the object from the list and re-insert it (very inefficient).  Objects are reference types.  Once you have a reference to the object, just update the object as it is one and the same as the object in the list.

Comment: One more suggestion.  FindIndex may return -1, in which case ElementAt will throw an exception.

Answer (score 5):

This was a new discovery today - after having learned the class/struct reference lesson!

You can use Linq and "Single" if you **know** the item will be found, because Single returns a variable...

```
myList.Single(x => x.MyProperty == myValue).OtherProperty = newValue;
```

Comment: Worked precisely for my issue, as I did not want to create a new List<T>, and only wanted to update ONE property on an object within my List<T>

Answer (score 3):

I found a way of doing it in one Line of code unsing LINQ:

```
yourList.Where(yourObject => yourObject.property == "yourSearchProperty").Select(yourObject => { yourObject.secondProperty = "yourNewProperty"; return yourObject; }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var index = yourList.FindIndex(x => x.yourProperty == externalProperty);
if (index > -1)
{
   yourList[index] = yourNewObject;   
}
```

yourlist now has the updated object inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is also worth mentioning that what Matt Roberts said applies to structs inside classes.

So even when you have a class (which will pass by reference, theoretically), a property which is a list of structs inside it will pass by value when you try to find it and change a value inside a given struct (on the list).

For instance (using the same code as Matt proposed):

```
ParentClass instance = new ParentClass();

var found = instance.ListofStruct.FirstOrDefault(c => c.TheValue == 1);
found.TheValue = 12;

foreach (var myStruct in instance.ListofStruct)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myStruct.TheValue);
}
Console.ReadLine();

public class ParentClass
{
    public List<MyStruct> ListofStruct { get; set; }
    public struct MyStruct
    { 
        public int TheValue { get; set; }
    }

    public ParentClass()
    {
        ListofStruct = new List<MyStruct>()
        {
            new MyStruct {TheValue = 10},
            new MyStruct {TheValue = 1},
            new MyStruct {TheValue = 145}
        };
    }
}
```

Will output: 10, 1, 145

Whereas changing the struct (inside the ParentClass) to a class, like this:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public List<MySubClass> ListofClass { get; set; }
    public class MySubClass
    {
        public int TheValue { get; set; }
    }

    public ParentClass()
    {
        ListofClass = new List<MySubClass>()
        {
            new MySubClass {TheValue = 10},
            new MySubClass {TheValue = 1},
            new MySubClass {TheValue = 145}
        };
    }
}
```

Will output: 10, 12, 145

Answer (score -1):

```
//Find whether the element present in the existing list

    if (myList.Any(x => x.key == "apple"))
       {
          //Get that Item
         var item = myList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.key == ol."apple");
        //update that item
         item.Qty = "your new value";
       }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the simplest and complete process, I used .Net 6:

```
public void UpdateGPA(Student student)
{
    Student student1 = students.First(x => x.Name == student.Name);
    students.Remove(student1);
    students.Add(student);                                  
}
```

where the class and list are:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public double GPA { get; set; } 
}   

List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
```

You can use FirstOrDefault and null checking.