# Update List element if object member is the smallest element in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have the following class.

```
public class DataDescr
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double age{ get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following List, containing elements of type DataDescr

```
List<DataDescr> data = new List<DataDescr>();

data.add(new DataDescr{ name = "Test_1", age = 20 });
data.add(new DataDescr{ name = "Test_2", age = 40 });
data.add(new DataDescr{ name = "Test_3", age = 10 });
data.add(new DataDescr{ name = "Test_4", age = 15 });
```

My goal is to **update the value of name in the list** of the element that has the lowest age value.

I have tried some approaches but nothing worked so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update an object in a List<> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190016/how-to-update-an-object-in-a-list-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @EminMesic No, this isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
var minAge = data.Min(x => x.Age);
data.Where(x => x.Age == minAge).ToList().ForEach(x => { x.Name = "NEW_VALUE"; });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = data.OrderBy(x => x.age).First();
item.name = "some name";
```

Comment: I don't want to change the order

Comment: Who said you will? This is order in purpose to find item, you will not change your list order.

Comment: I mean the goal is to update the value of the object in the list

Comment: LINQ `OrderBy` is non-mutational; it returns a new `IEnumerable`.

Comment: And that's what I've provided, find and update the specific item in your list. Just two lines of code. For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/

Answer (score 0):

```
var minAge = data.Min(a => a.age);
var dataWithMinAge = data.Where( a => a.age == minAge);
dataWithMinAge.Name = "Update to new value";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Very true.  1) Firstly fetch the minimum age in the list of data 2) Get the record of the user with minimum age 3) Now perform the operation of changing the name of the person with minimum age